How many ways to tile $4 \times N$ boards using tetrominoes, excluding rotations and reflections?
Recently I have come to consider using tetrominoes for a personal project (unrelated to math), I wanted to use some $4 \times N$ board tetromino tilings, but I've come face to face against a specific problem. There doesn't seem to be any thorough or complete list of them out there.
I have seen other people ask related questions such as tilings with only T-tetrominoes and dominoes, but the answers to those questions are unfortunately not useful to me.
I have unfortunately been reduced to just trying different permutations of tetrominoes by hand, one by one, which has gotten increasingly more complex (my lack of programming skills only making it a harder and longer process).
I have come up with answers for smaller $4 \times N$ boards, for the $4 \times 1$ board there's only one way using the I-tetromino, for $4 \times 2$ I have found $3$ possible tilings, for $4 \times 3$ I've found $8$, and for $4 \times 4$ I've found $22$ (which seems to be the right number).
However I'm having trouble going beyond there, going through all possible permutations for $4 \times 5$ and $4 \times 6$ is proving to be cumbersome, with the added possibility I might just miss one permutation, or include a reflection or rotation without being aware of it.
So I come to this place to see if anyone knows the answer to my small dilema, maybe it has been out there all along and I have missed it, or maybe there haven't been many people who have had this same question before.
(If there's also any way to calculate this on my own, I would really appreciate it.)

We can get this down to a linear recurrence sequence, over all the possible jagged extremities. A bit like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4577309/a-recursive-relation-for-the-number-of-ways-to-tile-a-2-x-n-grid-with-2x1-1x2, but we would have a different sequence for each possible extremity, with the extremity allowed to be somewhat jagged.

Some conventions
I'm used to Tetris. So I mentally see the 4 squares as width of the rectangle, and the $N$ as height. I imagine myself filling the rectangle from bottom to top. To be more specific, I want to place tiles one after the other in such a way that the next tile always covers the left-most open square in the bottom-most row that has open squares. (I don't worry about whether a tile could drop to that position coming from above or whether that drop would be blocked.)
Dealing with symmetry
The “excluding rotations and reflections” part of your question makes it a bit tricky. If we ignore the case of $N=4$, then your rectangle has three symmetries: reflection in a vertical axis, reflection in a horizontal axis, and rotation by $180^\circ$. Any given tiling may be symmetric under none, one, or all three of these symmetries. It can't be symmetric under two, because two of them imply the third.
Let $b_N$ be the total number of tilings with symmetric versions counted repeatedly. Let $c_N$ be the number of tilings symmetric under reflection in the vertical axis, $d_N$ the number of tilings symmetric under reflection in the horizontal axis, $e_N$ the number of tilings symmetric under rotation, and $f_N$ the number of tilings with all three forms of symmetry.
If we imagine a fully unsymmetric tiling, then $b_N$ will include four versions of them which are essentially the same once symmetry is taken into account. So $\frac14 b_N$ is a reasonable first approximation of the number you want. However, a pattern with a single symmetry is only included twice in $b_N$, not four times. So $\frac14 b_N$ will only count these half, and we correct for that by using $\frac14 b_N+\frac14 c_N+\frac14 d_N+\frac14 e_N$ instead. Keep in mind that a pattern with a single symmetry will occur twice in exactly one of $c_N$, $d_N$ or $e_N$, so that with the two counts in $b_N$ it gets counted exactly once in total. Now let's check what happens if a tiling has all the symmetries of the rectangle. Then it occurs exactly once in $b_N$, $c_N$, $d_N$ and $e_N$, and the count above works for that as well. We don't even need $f_N$.
Taken together, the number of tilings, with symmetric versions of the same tiling counted only once, is
$$a_N = \tfrac14\left(b_N+c_N+d_N+e_N\right)$$
If the rectangle is a square
For $N=4$ the rectangle is a square. The considerations above apply at a high level, but at a lower level a lot of things need to be done differently. That is because a square also has $90^\circ$ rotations, and reflections along the diagonals. For example, a fully non-symmetric pattern would occur in 8 symmetric variations in the basic count, instead of 4.
Since you write that you have the square worked out, I'll not go into more detail, but instead exclude $N=4$ again from all further considerations. But I can confirm that your count of 22 is correct.
The basic case
So how do you get $b_N$, the number of tilings with all symmetric versions counted repeatedly?
As a first step I construct a directed graph, or an NFA if you prefer. The nodes / states represent the shape of all the unfinished rows of the stack. The edges / transitions represent adding a single tile in such a way that the left-most open position of the bottom-most row of that unfinished part gets filled. If that results in a completed row, that row is no longer represented in the target state because finished rows are ignored in the state representation.
Each transition corresponds to placing one tile. A sequence of $N$ consecutive transitions corresponds to placing $N$ tiles, filling $4\times N$ squares of a conceptually infinitely high rectangle. Each tiling of your actual $4\times N$ rectangle can be described as a sequence of exactly $N$ transitions in this graph, starting with the “no unfinished rows” state and ending in that state as well.
In my code I got $142$ different states and $319$ transitions at first. You can reduce this a bit by dropping any dead ends, i.e. any states from which there is no path back to the “no unfinished rows” state. That gave me $80$ states and $230$ transitions between them. Not too bad for a computer to handle, still a bit confusing for a human to look at, so the following image is meant more for illustration than as a tool for actually working out the counts by hand:

If $B$ is the adjacency matrix of the directed graph, and $1$ is the index of the “no unfinished rows” state (the one at the top of the image), then $b_N=\left(B^N\right)_{1,1}$, i.e. the top-left entry of the $N$-th power of matrix $B$, is the number of distinct paths of length $N$ through the graph from state $1$ back to state $1$.
My code generated some numbers for this which match https://oeis.org/A174248. Looking good so far.
Vertical axis
To build tilings which have the vertical axis as their symmetry you can follow essentially the same approach, but make sure to place tiles in a symmetric way. That means that at each step you either place a single tile which is symmetric to itself in that position, or you place two non-overlapping tiles which are symmetric to one another.
The placement of two tiles in a single step is a problem when we want to count transitons and see that as number of tiles placed. To resolve this I will introduce a second class of states. Where the normal states indicate that “after the placement of the most recent tile, the shape will be as follows”, those additional states would represent “after the placement of one additional tile, the shape will be as follows”. So when placing two tiles, we transition first to that intermediate “half-pair” state, and then from there to the regular state. It is important that there is only a single transition from the “half-pair“ state to the regular state of the same shape. With this trick, we recovered that each transition corresponds to the placement of one piece, and also captured that after placing the first tile from a pair, there is exactly one way how the second tile may be placed.
In the following graph, the “half-pair” states are marked with a cyan border around the shape. Compared to the free placement of arbitrary tiles, this graph is way simpler. Starting with 14 states and 23 transitions, only 10 states and 19 transitions are left after dead end elimination.

Horizontal axis
When building a tiling that has a horizontal symmetry axis, you can classify your tiles into three groups: the tiles below the symmetry axis, the tiles above, and the titles that intersect it. There may be between zero and four tiles intersecting the symmetry axis, and that number will be odd if and only if $N$ is odd.
I would start by enumerating all the possible ways how $i$ tiles can intersect the symmetry axis in a self-symmetric way, for $0\le i\le 4$.



number of tiles
number of central configurations




0
1 (no tiles at all)


1
1 (single horizontal bar)


2
13 (various combinations of squares and vertical bars)


3
0


4
1 (4 vertical bars)



When you cut each of these configurations in half, you get the shape of the central pieces protruding into the space above. So based on that shape you can do the basic counting again, i.e. starting with the shape from the central configuration and ending with a straight line. That gives you all combinations for the upper part, and the lower is just a reflection of that. The sum over all possible central configurations yields $d_N$.
Some care might be needed because at least in theory the central configuration might present a shape that cannot occur in a situation where always the leftmost bottom square gets filled next. So make sure the graph accounts for all shapes from central arrangement that stand a chance of evolving to a straight line. In my experiments I have not found any other relevant states apart from the 80 included in my graph above.
Note that the single horizontal bar is the only possible central configuration for odd $N$, and in this case the lower and upper part are rectangles. From this it follows that
$$d_{2N+1}=b_N$$
Unfortunately the case of even $N$ is less simple, so the full machinery of constructing central arrangements and then counting the possible upper halves for each of them still makes sense.
Rotation
Rotations can be handled in the same way as reflection in the horizontal axis, namely by dividing the tiling into a central arrangement and a bottom and a top half. Even though the symmetry center is just a point, it makes sense to consider all tiles that intersect the central horizontal line to be part of the central arrangement.



number of tiles
number of central configurations




0
1 (no tiles at all)


1
1 (single horizontal bar)


2
27


3
18


4
21



Again you then count the number of upper half tilings with half the remaining tiles and add up all of those to get $e_N$.
Actual numbers
Below are the numbers for a fair number of possible sizes. $a_N$ is the column that directly answers your question. For single-digit $N$ I've compared the results against a fairly brute force computation, and they check out, so I have some confidence that they should be correct.



$N$
$a_N$
$b_N$
$c_N$
$d_N$
$e_N$
$f_N$




0
1
1
1
1
1
1


1
1
1
1
1
1
1


2
3
4
2
2
4
2


3
8
23
5
1
3
1


4
(22 with full symmetry) 41
117
13
13
21
5


5
125
454
28
4
14
2


6
550
2003
63
49
85
11


7
2347
9157
145
23
63
5


8
10463
40899
335
233
385
25


9
45141
179399
763
117
285
13


10
200254
796558
1742
998
1718
58


11
888167
3546996
3986
454
1232
28


12
3942146
15747348
9124
4504
7608
132


13
17465726
69834517
20861
2003
5523
63


14
77539847
310058192
47702
19814
33680
302


15
344252742
1376868145
109101
9157
24565
145


16
1528183678
6112247118
249538
88310
149746
690


17
6783239259
27132236455
570695
40899
108987
335


18
30113931126
120453362938
1305188
391264
665114
1580


19
133689558493
534754586459
2985041
179399
483073
763


20
593496664171
2373975139658
6826988
1738566
2951472
3612


21
2634742992977
10538953415410
15613658
796558
2146282
1742


22
11696713064557
46786795734201
35709199
7714197
13100631
8261


23
51926499253883
207705902269424
81668820
3546996
9530292
3986


24
230522443778337
922089495910044
186780966
34254486
58167852
18892


25
1023381376169508
4093525019450760
427177808
15747348
42302116
9124


26
4543204287530267
18172815762851891
976977867
152052381
258238929
43211


27
20169119912501181
80676477157992863
2234399523
69834517
187777821
20861


28
89538853854168520
358155408485052873
5110188867
675057197
1146375143
98823


29
397499092244690308
1589996356147750962
11687269292
310058192
833682786
47702


30
1764658973976759715
7058635861091707249
26729396115
2996759337
5089176159
226013


31
7834033533869887879
31336134069270036273
61131527611
1376868145
3701119487
109101


32
34778436566395999395
139113746089875727531
139811003069
13304019095
22593247885
516901


33
154395517378873008593
617582069173194269620
319755079952
6112247118
16430437682
249538


34
685424024211556146505
2741696095955565780304
731296599110
59061521554
100300685052
1182188


35
3042873909345350502878
12171495635608815247599
1672513589139
27132236455
72940938319
570695


36
13508545493773449130199
54034181970561198460723
3825126098357
262198727103
445273234613
2703721


37
59969886029818820251837
239879544110082747554838
8748263546864
120453362938
323816542708
1305188


38
266230530433388358751513
1064922121710404947597423
20007736505955
1164003805073
1976747097601
6183549


39
1181904785940757660075986
4727619143715299591554009
45758740346679
534754586459
1437553816797
2985041


40
5246952408503880137557973
20987809633896924838156673
104652633623327
5167487644821
8775590807071
14142095


41
23293339622336914269364384
93173358489099555184678928
239346049323780
2373975139658
6381868315170
6826988


42
103408536715383998802395412
413634146860926699327647705
547396939216351
22940554272147
38958388445445
32343729


43
459072234321709629967440766
1836288937285547723789369666
1251925443983860
10538953415410
28331682994128
15613658


44
2038006948148156600270500269
8152027792589488387744643435
2863219000718683
101842397822931
172951938816027
73971793


45
9047535464400363630301335220
36190141857594733626868838705
6548331680177287
46786795734201
125775860590687
35709199


46
40165661875730604522988724807
160662647502906221791795387141
14976377211386597
452119459468905
767803488656585
169177353


47
178311585542575310794678743598
713246342170266225344625059258
34251758361114002
207705902269424
558369826531708
81668820


48
791597101949234062043865526788
3166388407796852496880828948664
78335563686025472
2007140902859462
3408590044273554
386917448


49
3514219055976532639504428700525
14056876223905947999566414033838
179157533266177866
922089495910044
2478828538680352
186780966


50
15601036869612896079147484351378
62404147478451150531321285862362
409742653473043946
8910508404574604
15132106773924600
884900488



Numbers visualized
The following plot shows the numbers from the table on a logarithic scale. You will notice that they each follow a fairly constant slope, but also that $d_N$, $e_N$ and $f_N$ zig-zag a bit between even and odd $N$. The red line corresponds to $4.43940364021331446620^N$, where the base of that exponential is the largest real eigenvalue of the incidence matrix $B$ from the automaton. For large $N$ you get $\frac{b_{N+1}}{b_N}\approx4.43940364021331446620$ and also $a_N\approx\frac14b_N$ as the other terms become less and less relevant because they grow more slowly.

The code
I've uploaded the Python code which I wrote to derive the table above. It's not the highest quality code, more fire and forget style, but it can be used to easily compute a far longer table within reasonable time if someone desires to do so.
The code also includes the dot method which was used to generate the graphs above. The calls to that method have been removed so that the code doesn't write any files without explicit request, but they can be added easily if needed.
Various other pieces of code can print details along the way. Most of that is disabled by some default function argument, but if someone wants to better understand some of the code, enabling one of these might help.

Maybe A174248 for $b_{N}$ ?

@Anthony: Definitely A174248, which is why the last paragraph of “the basic case” links to that. I'm wondering whether I should submit the $a_N$ to OEIS.
